# Is Oracle Db Query Information Processed on Server or Client?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, security, process

We are having a discussion about data security and an issue came up that I need confirmation on. This is the scenario:

We have two Oracle databases: one on a source server and one a client server. The source server has sensitive information and has been completely secured and deemed compliant. We want to run a `group by` query to aggregate the data from the source and store it on the client where, once it's aggregated, the data will no longer be sensitive.

Simply put... there are three parts to this 1) the data on the source server, 2) the transmission of data over the network, and 3) the data on client server.

Can some explain where the aggregation occurs? And what data is being transmitted?

In others words, which way is it:

1. The data is first aggregated on the source server and what is sent over the network is just the aggregated data
2. The data is sent in detail from the source server over the network and then aggregated on the client server
3. It's a hybrid of both #1 or #2
4. Or ... something else I'm missing?

Comment: The aggregation takes place on the server where the query runs.

Comment: How is the data copied over?  Does it use database links?

Comment: Thanks Dan for the response. And Jon, yes. The source is accessed through dblinks. Unless you know otherwise, you cannot connect to a remote db any other way without an ETL too.l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle optimizes distributed queries to execute them as efficiently as possible, and especially it seeks to minimize the amount of data sent across the network. It will always try to run queries on a remote server and send only the result set to the local server. (The situation is more complicated when joining remote data with local data, but that doesn't seem to be your scenario). [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_appdev004.htm#ADMIN12198).

So you could run the query on your client server and be sure that the sensitive data remains on the source server and only the aggregate result set is transmitted (your option **#1**). However, if I were your security officer I would still be unhappy with this solution. It still means granting `select` access on sensitive tables to a user outside the secure database. That's risky.

A safer solution would be aggregate the data on the secure server, say with a materialized view. Your client server accesses that materialized view to get the aggregated data, either just through a query or view, or with another materialized view, depending on what you need.

The full-on solution would be to have a separate schema on the source database to host the materialized views, so that no outside user even has access to the schema which owns the sensitive data. Obviously maintaining a DMZ is additional overhead, but all security is overhead.

Comment: Thanks for that. Note that it is okay for users to have access to the sensitive data. They are developers who have access to see everything on the source server. They just can't do development there. There will be a third server involved where the final data will rest for end users who should not.

Comment: It's unusual for developers to have access to sensitive data in a Development context.

Answer (score 1):

If the policy is that never ever view the sensitive data in client server, then option one is your choice. As to implement option 2, client server will need to have the ability to query the original data from the source server.

To implement option 1, you can aggregate data by using Materialized Views on the source server and then use db link to copy aggregated data to client server.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but you may have misunderstood my question. I'm not look for what the best option is. I'm looking for what actually happens given my scenario